In Gitlab CI how to see how the rules have been evaluated?
I'm troubleshooting a rather complex setup of a pipeline with various jobs being created differently depending on many rules and variables in GitlabCI. Some rule is obviously not doing what it should as we end up in the wrong end state for our variables.
But it is rather tricky to follow. Especially when I have not found any way to see in the logs or somewhere how the rules for the jobs are evaluated.
What I have been doing is to try to create similar job/rule setup and have echoes in the script attributes ... but that is a lot of extra, error prone, job. That could be avoided if I could just see how the rules and variables were evaluated when the pipeline is setup...
Is this possible?
